# Existing workflow running instances will be lost if we re-configure the farm?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-manager, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I need to re-configure the workflow farm using WFM. What will happen to the existing workflow running instances? All of them will lost or Is there anyway to keep them?